# How to encode '<' & '>' Symbols in XML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

Since `<` & `>` as part of XML syntax. How to add these symbols as part of the data like

```
<Note>Have to have <> symbols</Note>
```

I have heard there are different types of data in which XML can be sent like CDATA etc, since character data parses each character it doesn't allow these symbols.

I do know about `&lt;` and `&gt;` but that isn't helpful.

Are there are any modes of data in which XML can be sent to avoid any tool recognizing the symbols?

Comment: I'm going to assume that you meant `&lt;` literally when you wrote that in your question. Do take not that Stack Overflow posts can contain HTML, and that to post XML literally you should use code markup as I have done in the edit.

Comment: In addition, a comment on the question: Why aren't entities like `&lt;` useful in your situation?

Comment: @YiJiang Thanks for the tip. I am new here and I dont understand how to use code markup and other formatting, are any any posts that explains it easily.....  and About lt;, it isnt helpful as in my application there is code in place to decode it back to symbol..so cant use that...but anyway i got my answer from phihag who had also provided the syntax. Thnx.

Comment: Clicking on the orange question mark on the right of the editor toolbar will give you information on how to do formatting with Markdown

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to represent characters which have special meaning in XML (such as `<` and `>`) in an XML document.

1. CDATA sections
2. As entities

A CDATA section can only be used in places where you could have a text node.

```
<foo><![CDATA[Here is some data including < and > (and &!) ]]></foo>
```

The caveat is that you can't include the sequence `]]>` as data in a CDATA section.

Entities can be used everywhere (except inside CDATA sections) and consist of `&`, then an identifier, then `;`.

```
<foo>Here is some data including &lt; and &gt; (and &amp;!)</foo>
```

> I do know about `&lt;` and `&gt;` but that isn't helpful.

It is how XML works. It is one of your only two options. It should not be a problem (if it is, then you need to explain why in your question).

Answer (score 14):

`<` is encoded as `&lt;`.
`>` is encoded as `&gt;`.
`"` is encoded as `&quot;`.
`&` is encoded as `&amp;`.

Alternatively, you can pack the whole data in a [CDATA section](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-cdata-sect) if it doesn't contain a CDATA section itself. If you're generating programatically, encoding each character is the better solution though.

Note that there is a plethora of XML libraries available for almost every language. Unless you want to learn about XML, I **strongly recommend using an XML library** instead of writing your own.

Comment: On the other hand, if you really want to acquire a deep understanding of XML, I strongly recommend writing you own library!

Answer (score 1):

You can encode as `&amp;` entity